# ngDoc @param {type} - the type is not rendered in documentation output

Tags: angularjs, ngdoc

I am using dgeni to document my angular 1.5.x project, wherever I have used
`@param {type} name description` the type is not rendered on the output.
I have followed the installation steps of dgeni from [this](http://toddmotto.com/documenting-angular-dgeni) tutorial. Please let me know what I am missing here.

Comment: Can you solve the problem?

Comment: Not yet. Its doable by through change of CSS but I have not found any options in the library or set up.